# Recommendation of Statistics Book

Tags: probability, statistics, reference-request, book-recommendation

Recommend a book for self study which contains the following topics. 
1. Probability theory 
2. Random variables 
3. Linear model 
4. Statistical inference 
5. Probability distributions

The book must be simple and graduate level. 
It  will be better if it is freely available on internet. 
It must contains problems.

Comment: So from the graduate level requirement can it be assumed that the student has studied measure spaces and lebesgue integration?

Comment: This is quite broad and is missing details as to what exactly you are looking for in these topics. You want one book covering all of them? I reckon you will get good recommendations of these individually if you search the site.

Comment: @StubbornAtom  I need one book covering all these topics in simple language with more examples and exercise.

Comment: @DavidReed  Yes !!